# asp.net session duration when user is constantly using the application

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a question and don't know wether it is good question to ask or not,

suppose I have a session in asp.net with timeout of 20 minutes, and my user is constantly using the particular application, will my session exipres after 20 minutes or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe , As long as the user is active and he is using the application, the session will be updated. If the user is idle for a long time and the session will be expired, then user has to sign in again for security reasons.

Refer [Session State document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178581(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)